# Show that $\lim_{p \to \infty}||x||_p=||x||_M$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let 
$$||x||_p=\left( \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$
and
$$||x||_M=\max\{|x_1|,|x_2|,...,|x_n|\},$$
norms in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that
$$\lim_{p \to \infty}||x||_p=||x||_M, \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n.$$

Comment: What kind of convergence are you referring to with $\lim_p ||x||_p$ ?

Comment: the norm $p$ of a element converg to norm of máximus of the element, when $p$(of norm $p$) convergs to infty.

Comment: Not sure I understand the downvotes. Searching for symbols can be a little difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $x = \big( x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n \big)$, denote $\ell = \max\big\{ \vert x_1 \vert , \ldots, \vert x_n \vert \big\}$.

Case 1. If $\ell = 0$, the proof is trivial.

Case 2, If $\ell > 0$, then 
 $$\big\| x \big\|_p = \left( \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \leq \big( n \ell^p \big)^{1/p} = n^{1/p} \cdot \ell \xrightarrow{p\to +\infty} \ell \,\, . $$
This implies that 
$$\limsup_{p\to+\infty} \big\| x \big\|_p\leq \ell \,\, .$$
On the other side,
$$ \big\| x \big\|_p = \left( \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \geq \ell  \Longrightarrow \liminf_{p\to+\infty} \big\| x \big\|_p\geq\ell   $$

Combine these two inequality, we can get the desired limit.

**Q.E.D.**